# build error for Xamarin IOS task "could not be loaded from the assembly"

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops

I'm getting this build error on an Azure Devops Pipeline build for Xamarin iOS

error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName" task could not be loaded from the assembly /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/10/s/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.1.0.6529/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/10/s/UITest/UITest.csproj]

Comment: What agent are you using? And have you add nuget restore task to your build definition? Please share the tasks in your definition here.

Comment: thanks, I'm using agent:  Azure Pipelines - Mac 10.14, and I also have a nuget restore step

Comment: I might add that I have another pipeline on another project set up the same way that works.  The difference is that this project has to be the old Xamarin PCL while the new one is .NET standard